# how to convert members of case class in Scala to List of Objects in Java

Tags: scala

I am trying to insert some values in `Cassandra` using Datastax Java driver.

I have a `case class` representing the values I want to insert.

```
case class User(firstname:String, lastname:String)
```

The `insert` method of `Cassandra`'s driver looks like

```
values(List<String> names, List<Object> values)
```

The table schema is

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    firstname text,
    lastname text,
    PRIMARY KEY ((firstname, lastname))
```

What is the way to convert `User` into `List<Object>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to get the `java.util.List<Object>` without reflection:

```
User("a","a").productIterator.toList.map(_.asInstanceOf[Object]).asJava
```

Comment: Thanks. I understood the conversion except the `asJava` part. Where is `asJava` method defined. I suppose `map` will create a `List[Object]` but I didn't find `asJava` in `List` class

Comment: I tried your solution and got this error 
`error: value asJava is not a member of List[Object]`

Comment: got it working. Had to import `import collection.JavaConverters._`

Answer (score 1):

Getting Map for case class prop:value with reflection, partitioning keys and values, converting to java lists.

```
val usr = User("John", "Doe")
val map = (Map[String, AnyRef]() /: usr.getClass.getDeclaredFields) {
    (acc, field) =>
        field.setAccessible(true)
        acc + (field.getName -> field.get(usr))
}

val keys = map.keys.init.toList
val vals = map.values.init.toList

import collection.JavaConverters._
new SomeClass().values(keys.asJava, vals.asJava)
```